# Is it possible to JOIN with a CTE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a query like this

```
WITH a AS (SELECT key FROM table) 
SELECT * 
FROM a 
  JOIN b;
```

which generates a syntax error in PostgreSQL 10.4.

Why does this error?

It looks like I will be creating a view instead. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You are missing the obligatory join condition `ON` or `USING`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing the JOIN condition:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT key FROM table) 
SELECT * 
FROM a 
  JOIN b ON a.key = b.key;
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the CTE, it is a simple syntax error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
JOIN b
-- something missing here
```

Here, `JOIN` defaults to an `INNER JOIN`, which requires some condition for which rows should be joined - generally either like `ON a.key = b.key` or `USING key`. The same would be true of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

If you wanted all the possible combinations (rare, but occasionally useful), you would use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a 
CROSS JOIN b;
```

Or the similar comma operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a, b;
```